# How to fix 'err="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n line 21: field routes not found in type config.plain"'

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to set up Alertmanager to send to 2 different receivers based on the value of a label in the Prometheus rule. For example, if responsible_team label equals web, send to the web team receiver. If reponsible_team label equals database, send t o the database team receiver.

I've followed Alertmanager's documentation and they say you should set up multiple routes with a match then labelName and labelValue underneath it.

```
route:
  group_by: ['alertname','entity']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 15m
  receiver: default

routes:
-  match:
     responsible_team: 'TestTeam'
   receiver: test_email
```

The expected result would be that any firing alerts in Alertmanager that have the responsible_team label as TestTeam would send an email to the email address defined in my test_email receiver. However, when I apply these changes and restart the service, I get the following error:

level=error ts=2019-07-11T22:00:29.0405339Z caller=main.go:325 msg="Loading configuration file failed" file="C:\Program Files\AlertManager\alertmanager.yml" err="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 21: field routes not found in type config.plain"

I've tried to update the version to the latest and that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that routes needs to be indented to be "under" route for the yaml to be valid
You can use the visual editor here https://prometheus.io/webtools/alerting/routing-tree-editor/ to debug your config file as well